Adding corner radius adds extra space on top when windowStyle is HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle
I'm using NavigationSplitView, and in detail view when I add corner radius, it adds extra space in place of title bar.
Below is the code that adds extra space on top when I add corner radius:

and works perfectly without corner radius:

NavigationSplitView(
    sidebar: { Text("sidebar") },
    detail: {
        Text("detail")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(.red)
            .cornerRadius(6)
        }
    )
.navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced)

Also window style in @main is HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle
WindowGroup {
    ContentView()
}
.windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())

Does anyone know why the corner radius in not working as expected when window style is HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle.

The area which is usually occupied by the title bar is excluded from the "safe area" of the window. Normally, the content of the window will not go into this area, unless the safe area edges are ignored.
When the background is applied using the modifier background(_:ignoresSafeAreaEdges:), safe area edges are ignored by default.

In the version without round corners, the safe area edges are being ignored and the red background extends to the top of the window.

By setting a corner radius, you are actually applying a clip shape. Since this is being applied after the background, it is clipping the red background back to the regular frame. This is why the background is only filling the safe area.


To fix, apply the background using background(alignment:content:) and add the the rounded corners to this background. This does not ignore the safe area edges by default, so add .ignoresSafeArea() to achieve this.
BTW, .cornerRadius is deprecated, so it is better to use .clipShape instead. This also makes it clear that the view is being clipped.
detail: {
    Text("detail")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background {
            Color.red
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6))
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
}


Alternatively, if you would like the main content of the detail view to ignore the safe area edges too, just add .ignoresSafeArea() to the whole view, after the clip shape:
detail: {
    Text("detail")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(.red)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6))
        .ignoresSafeArea()
}


The result is not quite the same - you will notice that the text for "sidebar" and "detail" are no longer vertically aligned. This is because, the detail view now extends to the top of the window, so its vertical middle is a little higher than the sidebar middle. In the previous version above, only the background was extending to the top, the actual content was still respecting the safe area edges.
